# Unknown error on pause()

Tags: java, android, media-player, rtsp

I get the following error

> 12-15 16:54:37.125: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6032): error (-2147483648, 0)

when trying to execute this code in a service:

```
MediaPlayer mp = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    if (mp == null) {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Not playing, starting stream...");
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(getString(R.string.address_p3));
            mp.prepare(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        mp.start();
    } else { 
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Playing, pausing stream...");
        try { mp.pause(); } 
        catch (Exception e) {} 
    }
}
```

When the service is first called and no `MediaPlayer-object` exists, the stream is started correctly.

But when the `onStart()`-method is called again (with the player streaming) I get the above error code.

I can't find any information about this error code, so I turn to you for help. Replacing `mp.pause()` with `mp.stop()` makes it work.

Could it be that the stream does not support pausing? It's an online radio stream (RTSP) in the SDP format.

Comment: Have you tried your code with other streams and media formats? Also, if you have a sample RTSP URL, that'd be useful for testing.

Comment: I have only tried it with one stream (rtsp://lyssna-mp4.sr.se/live/mobile/SR-P3.sdp). I can try another format and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read [this tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/) about the bloggers custom StreamingMediaPlayer class for Android, in the tutorial he talks about how he accomplishes pausing a stream.

This could be helpful for you, if it doesn't solve what you need at least it gives you another perspective on how to achieve such a task.